# Keep alive with MyEnTunnel or other SSH-background tunnel app

Tags: windows-7, ssh, tunnel, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I'm successfully using MyEnTunnel to forward traffic to a remote SOCKS-server. If I don't use the tunnel for a while the connection seems to turn stale, but doesn't fail, hence the browser  waits for an answer. If I disconnect the SSH-connection and reconnect everything is fine again. Is there some way to send keep alive packages without requiring another tool? Or is there a good alternative tool? Any workaround is good.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the `ServerAliveInterval` ssh option. There should be an option `ExecArguments` in `myentunnel.ini` where you can add `-o ServerAliveinterval=30`. Your client should then send some package every 30 seconds to keep the server happy.